# MultiThreading - Threads are getting created with the same properties instead of proper looping

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a list of brands and I want to set brand specific properties to each Object and run a thread of it.

However, when I run the below code... it creates multiple threads of same brand and leaves out few brands.

brightCoveVideoInfoPullerThread is a runnable class. In the object of this I am adding brand specific properties through BrightCoveAPIParam.

```
for (int i = 0; i < brands.size(); i++) {
    String brand = brands.get(i);
    brightCoveVideoInfoPullerThread.setBrightCoveAPIParam(properties.get(brand));
    Thread t = new Thread(brightCoveVideoInfoPullerThread,
    "BrightCovePullerThreadFor" + brand);
    t.start();
}
```

e.g

Brightcove Poller for HEALTHCOM

Brightcove Poller for HEALTHCOM

Brightcove Poller for FOODANDWINE

Brightcove Poller for FOODANDWINE

Comment: Looks like you need to create a new instance of `brightCoveVideoInfoPullerThread` on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the same instance of `brightCoveVideoInfoPullerThread` on every iteration of the loop. Changing a property of that instance using the setter will update the property for all threads, since all threads are running that same instance.

Create a new instance of it inside the loop, so that each thread has its own instance:

```
for (String brand : brands) {
  BrightCoveVideoInfoPullerThread brightCoveVideoInfoPullerThread = new ...;
  brightCoveVideoInfoPullerThread.setBrightCoveAPIParam(properties.get(brand));

  Thread t = new Thread(brightCoveVideoInfoPullerThread, "BrightCovePullerThreadFor" + brand);
  t.start();
}
```